# Returning array values to HTML ends up writing the product 10 times, instead of once

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I am trying to return 2 array values, product name and product price, I did this in HTML:

```
<tbody>
      {% for name in farmingMerchantName %} {% for npcBuy in
      farmingMerchantPrices %}
      <tr>
        <td>{{ name }}</td>
        <td>temp</td>
        <td>{{ npcBuy }}</td>
        <td>temp</td>
      </tr>
      {% endfor%} {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
```

and I did this in python:

```
@app.route('/bresell')
def reSell():
    farmingMerchantPrices = [
        "5",  # cocoa beans
        "12",  # brown mushroom
        "2.328125",  # carrot
        "8",  # pumpkin
        "2.328125",  # wheat
        "12",  # red mushroom
        "2.328125",  # potato
        "4",  # sand
        "5",  # sugar cane
        "2",  # melon
    ]
    farmingMerchantName = [
        "Cocoa Beans",
        "Brown Mushroom",
        "Carrot",
        "Pumpkin",
        "Wheat",
        "Red Mushroom",
        "Potato",
        "Sand",
        "Sugar Cane",
        "Melon"
    ]

    return render_template('resell.html', farmingMerchantPrices=farmingMerchantPrices, farmingMerchantName=farmingMerchantName)
```

And here is the output:
[image: output]

And it goes on like that for all the products in "farmingMerchantName" array.

I need to to write the product, with the correct price (name1 = price1, name2 = price2, and so on).

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `zip` method in order to do this:

```html
<tbody>
      {% for name, npcBuy in zip(farmingMerchantName, farmingMerchantPrices) %}
      <tr>
        <td>{{ name }}</td>
        <td>temp</td>
        <td>{{ npcBuy }}</td>
        <td>temp</td>
      </tr>
      {% endfor%} {% endfor %}
</tbody>
```

Problem with your code is that it's becoming nested loop, as you are using two for loop consecutively.

If you get any jinja error regarding `zip`, then you can do the following:

```py
app.jinja_env.globals.update(zip=zip)
```

Comment: I get this: jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'zip' is undefined

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: Still seem to get the error, is the arguments supposed to be inside of my app route? or under my "app = Flask(__name__)" or something like that?

Comment: Could you post your changes in the OP?

Comment: The updated changes in my answer should be done below `app = Flask(__name__)`.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, some stuff popped up. But yes, I have it underneath my "app = flask(__name__)", I'll look a bit into "zip" on the Jinja documentation!

Comment: Well I think its correct, maybe. I still get the error "jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'zip' is undefined", and I also tried this: app.jinja_env.globals.update(zip=zip) | but it then says "Method 'jinja_env' has no 'globals' member", I think I might have just done something wrong though.

Comment: Could you post the whole code or could you share me the repo, it will be easy.

Comment: here is my python: https://pastebin.com/qNmaXcCB & here is my HTML: https://pastebin.com/ZeqHVskw

Comment: It's working properly in my machine. Could you save and restart it?

Comment: The restart worked! Though, still have the 'problem' "Method 'jinja_env' has no 'globals' member", strange... It works though! displaying names and prices just fine :)